# Array filter with more than one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to filter an array with a text match with many elements. But my implementation only uses the first element to filter the array.

```
dataSource =
    dataSource &&
    dataSource.itemList.filter((result: any) =>
      (
        result.lotNumber ||
        result.year ||
        result.make ||
        result.model ||
        result.stockNumber ||
        result.vin ||
        result.mileageType ||
        result.intColor ||
        result.engine ||
        result.crGrade ||
        result.transmission ||
        result.sellerName
      )
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchedText.toLowerCase())
    );
```

In my solution, it only works for `result.lotNumber`. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: i used && then it does not work for anything

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

Concat the values and do not use boolean operators.

```
dataSource =
    dataSource &&
    dataSource.itemList.filter((result: any) =>
      (
        '' +
        result.lotNumber + ' ' +
        result.year + ' ' +
        result.make + ' ' +
        result.model + ' ' +
        result.stockNumber + ' ' +
        result.vin + ' ' +
        result.mileageType + ' ' +
        result.intColor + ' ' +
        result.engine + ' ' +
        result.crGrade + ' ' +
        result.transmission + ' ' +
        result.sellerName
      )
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchedText.toLowerCase())
    );
```

By using `||`, the search is based on the first value not falsy.

You can add spaces to prevent that the concatenated values will match something by error.

Example:

If
result.model = 'V' and
result.stockNumber = '2'

By looking for 'V2', you'll have a match although it shouldn't. By adding spaces, you prevent that.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;) Check the last edit! It could help you too!

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing the [answer from sjahan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64168972/5605822), you can itterate the object keys of `result` without adding them one by one manually:

```
dataSource =
    dataSource &&
    dataSource.itemList.filter((result: any) =>
      (Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key])).join(' ')
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchedText.toLowerCase())
    );
```

```js
const itemList = [{
  lotNumber: '123',
  year: '2020',
  make: 'doe',
  model: 'model',
}, {
  lotNumber: '456',
  year: '2019',
  make: 'jane',
  model: 'othermodel',
}];

const result = (search) => itemList.filter((result) =>
  (Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key])).join(' ')
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(search.toLowerCase())
);

console.log(result('123'));
console.log(result('jane'));
```